# PHP try/catch error

Tags: php, psql

I have a PHP psql query. I am doing try catch to prevent Duplicates. When I ran the script I can see it's inserting something into my DB. But when I check my DB it's empty.

```
 foreach($data as $n){
 $query = $psql->pdo_prepared("INSERT INTO students(id,email,address,phone)VALUES".myFunction($array);
  }
```

and I have a PHP class to handle the exception:

```
 public function pdo_prepared($query,array){
     try{
               // some logic
        }
          catch(EXCEPTION $e){
                  //empty
       }
}
```

The reason why I am doing try catch is to catch duplicates and ignore it. If I throw an exception in my catch block my insert statement won't execute because my current data contains duplicates.

Comment: Your code is not valid. Missing a closing brace `)`. What you `myFunction()` do?

Comment: @IncredibleHat which syntax error?

Comment: @Syscall it's a function which implode my array

Comment: The function `pdo_prepared()` requires 2 arguments. Seems only one given.

Comment: Syscall caught one, then theres a `.` instead of a `,`, and then you have just a floating `array`... and consider case with `Exception`.

Comment: You can add a unique index to your table and specify that duplicates should be ignored in your insert statement.

Comment: @Don'tPanic how to say ignore if duplicate exist

Comment: Which database are you using? PostgreSQL? I wasn't sure if that's what you meant by psql.

Comment: @Syscall I forget to mention the 2 argument in my function above

Comment: @Don'tPanic yes I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: @Don'tPanic in mysql we can use Insert Ignore but it's not supported in PostgreSQL

Comment: I don't use postgres much, but according to their docs it looks like `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` should be equivalent.

Comment: @Don'tPanic i have tried that but didn't work that's why I switched to try catch

Comment: Do you add the options of PDO to emit exception?